# Read User Input and then outputted to a file

Tags: shell-script

I want to create a ifcfg-file in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ and then create a script that reads user input and outputs it to the ifcfg-file

example lines will be like:

Onboot: Yes or No(they either input yes or no)

and then it will output it like "Onboot=Yes"

After that it will output and write it to that new ifcfg-file

It will also have just regular input like when asked to input "ipaddr"

If you can just help me get it started and then I can take it from there. All help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a script to start with.
It takes the `port name` as input, as `ifcfg` files match the name of port, so if the provided port name is invalid it throws error.
Also, you can add further options to add like `IPADDR`, `DEVICE`, etc which if present in the ifcfg-file will be replaced with new value provided, else it will be appended to the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

function usage() {
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "$0 <port-name>"
}

function input_to_file() {
    param=$1
    value=$2
    portname=$3
    ifcfgfile="/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-$portname"
    echo $param=$value
    grep -q "^$param=" $ifcfgfile && sed "s/^$param=.*/$param="$2"/" -i $ifcfgfile ||
    echo $param="$value" >> $ifcfgfile
}

if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
    usage;
    exit 1;
fi

portname=$1

# Validate the port-name passed
ifconfig $portname &> /dev/null
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Invalid port name passed"
    exit 1
fi    

ifcfgfile="/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-$portname";
# Create file if not present for a valid port. This is actually not required if you are creating file prior to running script.
if [ ! -f $ifcfgfile ]; then
    touch $ifcfgfile
fi

echo -n "ONBOOT=[yes/no]: ";
param="ONBOOT"
read value
input_to_file $param $value $portname
```

Further enhancement to this script would be to validate the inputs, like if value for `ONBOOT` is other than `yes`/`no`, throw error, if invalid `IPADDR` is passed, throw error, etc. However, I leave it to you on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't wait to see how this works i appreciate all the help. if i have any more questions please forgive me i am fairly new to scripting but I am very driven to learn.

Comment: @Burritoboy if this answer is helpful for you, please don't hesitate to upvote it :)